# How to have 0 at the bottom of the canvas [Chart.JS]

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've got a chart in which the data is all 0 and I can click on buttons to scroll trough it.
But when it starts, and all data values are 0. I've tried setting the `min` and `beginAtZero` but it keeps putting the line in the center and show the -1 value underneath.

[image: See image]

I really can't figure out how to keep the line at the bottom when all values are 0.
When one value is not 0, the line graph starts at the bottom on 0.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=chart.js+beginAtZero+does+not+work+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @mplungjan I tried looking around and tested multiple things, but that 'similar' question does not answer my question. I want the line to not be in the center, be at the bottom and have the -1 value not show.

Comment: So post a [mcve] so we can re-open and answer. Just a picture and a "beginAtZero" does not work, is not enough for us to understand any of your issues